# Use purrr to collapse a vector of characters into a string of character

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, stringr

I want to use purrr to concatenate a character field in to tibble into a string.

```
d <- tibble(x = letters, y = c(rep(1,13), rep(2,13)) )
d
# output desired
tibble(y      =  c(1,2), 
       result =  c(stringr::str_c(letters[1:13],collapse = ","), stringr::str_c(letters[14:26], collapse = ",")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `purrr` function you want to use; but you can do the following in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(result = paste(x, collapse = ","))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#      y result
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m
#2     2 n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
```

Or using `nest` (in response to your comment)

```
d %>% group_by(y) %>% 
    nest(result = x) %>% 
    mutate(result = map_chr(result, ~paste(unlist(.x), collapse = ",")))
```

Comment: That is fantastic.  I had tried that approach with no luck.  I was think of trying to use nest and purrr::reduce

Comment: @HarlanNelson Yes you could use `nest` as well. But that's perhaps a bit of overkill here.

Comment: I simplified my  actual application, but your solution will work.  I would be nice to see it with a mapping function.

Comment: @HarlanNelson I've added an example using `nest`. Please take a look.

Comment: @HarlanNelson That's odd. I don't get an error with the sample data `d` you give. Do you get the error with the sample data or with a different dataset? I think the syntax of `nest` changed in recent `tidyr` versions. I'm using `tidyr_1.0.0`.

Comment: I just installed the github version tidyr_1.0.0.9000.